# Saving a string array to CSV

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, export-to-csv

I have a 25194081x2 matrix of strings called s1. Below an outlook of how the data looks like.

[image]

I am trying to save this matrix to csv. I tried the code below but for some reason it saves the first column of the vector twice (side by side) instead of the two columns.

What am I doing wrong?

```
fileID= fopen('data.csv', 'w') ;
 fprintf(fileID, '%s,%s\n', [s1(:,1) s1(:,2)]);
 fclose(fileID)
```

Comment: Dont merge the columns to a string array like you do now, but provide them as separate arguments, and loop over the rows of `s1`: `fprintf(fileID, '%s,%s\n', s1(k,1), s1(k,2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont merge the columns to a string array like you do now, but provide them as separate arguments, and loop over the rows of `s1`:

```
fileID= fopen('data.csv', 'w') ;
for k = 1:size(s1,1)
    fprintf(fileID, '%s,%s\n', s1(k,1), s1(k,2));
end
fclose(fileID)
```

Or, if you're using >R2019a, you can use `writematrix`:

```
writematrix(s1, 'data.csv');
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying this now. It's a very large matrix so it may take some time to loop. If it works once it's done I will accept the answer.

Comment: @phdstudent not sure if its faster, but you can also use `writematrix`

Answer (score 0):

My version of MATLAB (R2016a) does not have the `string` type available yet, but your problem is one I was having regularly with cell arrays of character vectors. The trick I was using to avoid using a loop for `fprintf` should be applicable to you.

Let's start with sample data as close to yours:

```
s1 = {'2F5E8693E','al1 1aj_25';
      '3F5E8693E','al1 1aj_50';
      '3F5E8693E','al1 1aj_50';}
```

Then this code usually executed much faster for me than having to loop on the matrix for writing to file:

```
% step 1: transpose, to get the matrix in the MATLAB default column major order
s  = s1.' ;

% step 2 : Write all in a long character array
so = sprintf('%s, %s\n', s{:} ) ;

% step 3 : write to file in one go (no need loop)
fid = fopen('data.csv', 'w') ;
fprintf(fid,'%c',so) ;
fclose(fid) ;
```

---

The only step slightly different for you might be step 2. I don't know if this syntax will work on a matrix of `string` as good on a cell array of characters, but I'm sure there is a way to get the same result: *a single long vector of characters*. Once you get that, `fprintf` will be uber fast to write it to file.

note: If the amount of data is too large and with a limited memory you might not be able to generate the long `char` vector. In my experience, it was still faster to use this method in *chuncks* (which would fit in memory) rather than looping over each line of the matrix.